# What does the "-d" stand for in xargs -d

Tags: command-line, sed, xargs

What does the `-d` mean in the below?

```
sed 's/^ *//' < /tmp/list.txt | xargs -d '\n' mv -t /app/dest/
```

Comment: Unix commands are documented in manpages; use `man xargs` in this case and search for `-d`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort to search for an answer before asking.

Comment: @dhag, `man xargs` would not be useful here if run on a non-GNU system as those `-d` and `-t` are GNU extensions.

Comment: You’re right, Stéphane, of course.

Comment: this isn't a great question, but it is relevant to unix & linux so it's not off-topic.   And pretty nearly any question here can be answered with RTFM so that's not a reason to close it either (downvote maybe, close no).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!!  Especially those who tried to help vs. hate.

I'm on a mac, using iTerm2 & OhMyZsh.  

I tried for hours searching the internet but found nothing, searching hyphen d, -d, linux -d, unix -d, and couldn't find anything.  

Downvote me all you want, but I did attempt for hours to find the answer to this question.  

I asked an old friend, who told me to try 'man xargs' or 'man -d' or 'man xargs -d', but the terminal didn't return anything related to '-d'.

So congratulations...unix.stackexchange.com is now the only place on the internet with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man xargs`:

> --delimiter=delim
>   -d delim
>   Input items are terminated by the specified character. Quotes and
>   backslash are not special every character in the input is taken
>   literally. Disables the end-of-file string, which is treated like
>   any other argument. This can be used when the input consists of
>   simply newline-separated items, although it is almost always
>   better to design your program to use --null where this is
>   possible. The specified delimiter may be a single character, a
>   C-style character escape such as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal
>   escape code. Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are understood as
>   for the printf command. Multibyte characters are not supported.

Note the comments to question and take them to heart. This answer could easily been found by either checking your own `man` page, or using your favorite search engine to search for an on-line version of the `man` page, or searching for `man xargs -d`.

Comment: If you accept the answer, please mark it "accepted".